# Error in if statement - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R and running into a problem that seems to have been well addressed on here but I'm struggling to implement it to my own situation.. Would appreciate any help on the code below! Thank you!

`for(i in 1:39644) {if(newsShort$shares[i] >= 1400) {newsShort$popular[i] = "yes"} else {newsShort$popular[i] = "no"} }`

Error in if (newsShort$shares[i] >= 1400) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(newsShort$shares[i], 1400) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: just do `ifelse(newsShort$shares>= 1400, 'yes', 'no')` The issue is because some values are NA thus cannot be compared to 1400

Answer (score 0):

Just like the warning message says - the `>=` operator is not meaningful for factors.  Convert `newsShort$shares` to a numeric vector and you'll be good